# "Failed to Get Framework Assemblies Local Path During Pushing Edge Package" message on Azure Stream Analytics Edge Module deployment

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-edge

I Had a very simple ASA edge job depolyed and running on a device for 1 week, and as of last thursday (11/07/2019), the module disappeared from my device and I can no longer add it. It returns the following message: "Failed to Get Framework Assemblies Local Path During Pushing Edge Package".

It looks like the ASA job definition is not being saved on the storage container. I tried to configure the storage account/container both manually and automatically, and when I clieck save, it shows thh operation successful message, the logs show that the job received an update, but if I open the storage account setting on the ASA job, it is not configured. If I explore the storage container, it´s empty.

the storage account is configured as blob account, hot, public accessible.

The region is Central (US).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a region bug. We created the ASA job on the East US region and it worked. Go figure...